# Android Proximity alert with multiple POI

Tags: java, android, alert, proximity

I have a database of lat and long with ID's and have retrieved this using json and want to apply the proximity alert to the geo locations in the array.
I am unsure if the array is being passed properly or if the proximity alert.java is being invoked properly

This is the DB retrieval

```
public class retrieveDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    String result = "";
    InputStream is = null;

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://cs1.ucc.ie/~am32/getDB.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();

            Log.i("json string", result);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data = null;

            System.out.println("Length"+ jArray.length());
            Log.d("DB","Length"+jArray.length());

            for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){

                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    int id = json_data.getInt("ID") ;
                    //String title = json_data.getString("Title"); 
                    double latitude = json_data.getDouble("Lat"); 
                    double longitude = json_data.getDouble("Lon"); 

                    //Adds proximity to POI's
                    ProxAlert inst = new ProxAlert();
                    inst.addProximityAlert(latitude,longitude, id);
                    //
                    inst.saveCoordinatesInPreferences((float)latitude, (float)longitude);

                    //prints to logCat
                    System.out.println(id+"&"+latitude+"&"+longitude);


            }
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            Log.e("log_tag","Failed data as:\n"+result);
    }
        return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    // invoked on UI thread publishProgress(Progress...).
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // result of background comp is passed to this step its invoked on the ui thread
    super.onPostExecute(result);

}
```

}

and my Proximity Alert class

```
public class ProxAlert extends Activity {

private static final long POINT_RADIUS = 10;
private static final long PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION = -1;

private static final String POINT_LATITUDE_KEY = "POINT_LATITUDE_KEY";
private static final String POINT_LONGITUDE_KEY = "POINT_LONGITUDE_KEY";

private LocationManager locationManager;
private static final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT= "com.example.try0.ProximityIntentReceiver";

void addProximityAlert (double latitude, double longitude, int id){

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt("title", id);
    extras.putDouble("lat", latitude);
    extras.putDouble("lon", longitude);

    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT + id);
    //intent.putExtra("alert", "it works");
    intent.putExtra(PROX_ALERT_INTENT, extras);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    //ProximityIntent will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected
    locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude,longitude,POINT_RADIUS,PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION,proximityIntent);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT + id);
    registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReciever(), filter);

}

void saveCoordinatesInPreferences(float currentlatitude, float currentlongitude){
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(getClass().getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putFloat(POINT_LATITUDE_KEY, currentlatitude);
    prefsEditor.putFloat(POINT_LONGITUDE_KEY, currentlongitude);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}

Location retrievelocationFromPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(getClass().getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Location location = new Location("POINT_LOCATION");
    location.setLatitude(prefs.getFloat(POINT_LATITUDE_KEY, 0));
    location.setLongitude(prefs.getFloat(POINT_LONGITUDE_KEY, 0));
    return location;
}
```

}

I'd really appreciate some help its been a lot of staring and confusing

Comment: so what is happening when you run it?

Comment: I have a receiver set to show a notification when entering and exiting but it doesn't appear and the only error in the logCat is `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:Vale GAP` GAP is the title of one of the values

Comment: well you know that your data is being caught in an exception, i dont know too much about JSON, but that means that that try block isnt being executed because its caught right?

Comment: Thanks I think I was trying to encode it twice once in the php and again in the above code but now its a new set of errors `log_tag(11124): Error in http connection java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
E/log_tag(11124): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
E/log_tag(11124): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
E/log_tag(11124): Failed data as:`

Comment: its saying you have no connection

Comment: Thanks for the help JRowan one more question i've run it a couple more times, theres still no notification or anything but there are also no errors what would be the best way to find out whats going on and why its till not working. thanks again

Comment: i never used an activity like that, i dont see an on create, you never instantiate your location manager, i never did it from an activity, i started a service from an activity that does all the proximitys, it works perfectly, you could probably alter it to work for you, you want it

Comment: i put up this service, idk, maybe you have the order wrong, but compare it to my service because my service runs perfectly, it just reads from a database instead of JSON

Answer (score 0):

here is my service, this works perfectly, i know it does its on the market, just where the database is if you plug in your JSON maybe you can alter it to your needs

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ProximityService extends Service{
    String proximitysd = "com.apps.ProximityService";
    int n = 0;
    private BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    MyLocationListener locationListenerp;
    public ProximityService() {


    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mybroadcast = new ProximityIntentReceiver();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);





        double lat;
        double lng;
        float radius = 50f;
        long expiration = -1;
         MyDBAdapter db = new MyDBAdapter(this);
            Cursor cursor;
            db.read();
            cursor = db.getAllEntries();
            boolean go = cursor.moveToFirst();
            while(cursor.isAfterLast() != true){
                lat = cursor.getInt(MyDBAdapter.LATITUDE_COLUMN)/1E6;
                lng = cursor.getInt(MyDBAdapter.LONGITUDE_COLUMN)/1E6;
                String what = cursor.getString(MyDBAdapter.ICON_COLUMN);
                String how = cursor.getString(MyDBAdapter.FISH_COLUMN);
                String proximitys = "com.apps.ProximityService" + n;
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(proximitys);
                registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter );

                Intent intent = new Intent(proximitys);

                intent.putExtra("alert", what);
                intent.putExtra("type", how);
                PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, n, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                locationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lng, radius, expiration, proximityIntent);
                //sendBroadcast(new Intent(intent));

                n++;
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            db.close();
            cursor.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Proximity Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try{
            unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            Log.d("reciever",e.toString());
        }


    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Proximity Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(proximitys);
        //registerReceiver(mybroadcast,filter);


    }
    public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
         private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

            Boolean entering = arg1.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
            String here = arg1.getExtras().getString("alert");
            String happy = arg1.getExtras().getString("type");



             NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, arg1, 0);        

                    Notification notification = createNotification();

                    notification.setLatestEventInfo(arg0, 
                        "Entering Proximity!", "You are approaching a " + here + " marker.", pendingIntent);

                    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);


                }

                private Notification createNotification() {
                    Notification notification = new Notification();

                    notification.icon = R.drawable.icon;
                    notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

                    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

                    notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
                    notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
                    notification.ledOffMS = 1500;


                    return notification;
                }
            //make actions



    }
     public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I was here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {            
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }

}
```